# Geometry fading away into fog

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

[image: monument valley]

I want to achieve the same effect of geometry blending into the fog in blender. I tried doing this with a plane alpha blend and a noise texture but it didn't work
I wondered how it's possible to achieve this effect using blenders eevee renderer thanks.

Comment: I suppose you would like to use eevee?

Comment: yep i am about to give up dont think its possible :(

Comment: giving up is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, using AOVs you can create a custom z-height layer that you can then composite over your image and get the disappearing effect that way.
[image]

First, add a custom Shader AOV and set it to Value. And while you are at it also enable transparency.

[image]
[image]

Then in your material for all the pillars and objects you want to fade away assign the z position to the Shader AOV with this node setup:

[image]

Then you can create the fadeout and composite it over your original image using the following nodes in the compositor:

[image]

If you have any questions feel free to ask and keep in mind nothing is impossible.

Comment: Interesting, I've never worked with _Shader AOV_ and didn't know what it's for. But for this task I find using the _Mist Pass_ much more comfortable and just like made for it as the name suggests.

Comment: The problem with the mist pass is that it gives the distance from the camera so the objects will disappear not based on their actual height but the distance from the camera if you look more or less straight down it works but if you tilt the camera too much the effect is a different one

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. I was more thinking of a homogenous mist overall and then the distance from the camera would be relevant, but this is more like ground fog so my method won't work that well. Anyone, maybe someone learns how to use the _Mist Pass_ from my answer and for everything else there is your answer :)

Comment: i dont know what exclude bg add fade on pillar nodes are :p

Comment: The "Exclude background" node is a renamed _Math_ node and the "Add fade on pillars" is a renamed _Alpha Over_ node. And the "Bacckground" node is a renamed _RGB_ node. @Phönix64 It is not a good idea to rename nodes without any explanation. Beginners often cannot recognize just by color or in-/outputs what nodes they are actually. This may be helpful in your workflow to remember what they are used for, but it's not helping in answers here.

Comment: Uh thank you sorry yea will change that

Comment: @Phönix64 amazing stuff thank you so much :3333

Comment: @Phönix64 i noticed these white lines when i zoom in any ideas what might be causing it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16nMLZ5Apa8ZLdE9zpTTcxYsQwDODTmqq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is an artefact of multiplying the alpha mask, you can try adding a Dialet /Erode node and set distance to -1, https://imgur.com/a/WRUGL0z

Comment: @Phönix64 that fixed i really appreciate the help thanks again :)

Comment: @Phönix64 hii i was wondering if its possible to apply the aov to all the objects in the scene uniformly regardless of the height
i want the vertical column to look like the rest
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QY0xdU8E7xOuBWLaBM_7ErHx5Z9hUaM_/view?usp=sharing
but when i use the same material(which has the aov) on all the objects it looks like this i think because column is lower than others
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rkaplHn0sdtFlZqyGHt_1aZLU_3mY1S/view?usp=sharing
tried giving it a const value
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Kwo3BiN6fclrOIVzKyMr9rAO_Rz022f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mangojuiceI I am not sure whether I understand you correctly. Could you maybe share your blend file using blend-exchange? The z position gives the global how far up you are if you want to get the local z you can try swapping the Geometry position for a Texture Coordinate generated or object, make sure to apply the scale.

Comment: @Phönix64 this is how i want it to look like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19uXvuRpti6sxrv51v97YbukMwBfUM1Z-/view

this is how it looks with the changes you suggested looks like the effect is only applied halfway which is weird:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIZ4GnTsI_jttS1CsWY3kMqMKbzXgetZ/view

tried other stuff like using object instead of generated changing rotation scale etc:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LetnMVh9iCXaJi5gSIfegSxKJl-b0vX8/view

my blendfile:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ikoa_YMzAokzMkZ7ckj-mY_uvtD4SMrr/view

Answer (score 1):

This is a good application for the *Mist Pass*, it is perfect for that and you can switch between *Eevee* and *Cycles*, it works in both render engines.

1. Enable *Mist* under *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* > *Data*.

   [image: enable mist pass]
2. This automatically enables the *Mist Pass* settings in the *World Properties* where you can set the *Start*, *Depth* and *Falloff*.

   [image: world properties mist pass]
3. If you now also enable *Show* > *Mist* in the camera's *Viewport Display* settings you can simply change the settings in *World Properties* according to where you want your mist to appear.

   [image: camera show mist]

As you can see in the following image, by enabling the camera's *Mist* display, the camera now shows a line representing the start and end of the *Mist Pass*, where the *Start* value is the distance from the camera where the pass begins, and the endpoint is the start distance from the camera plus the depth, and you can tweak the settings in the *World Properties* so that your objects are within this range (for example).

[image: viewport display of mist pass]

After rendering, the *Render Layers* node now also has an output *Mist*. The *Mist Pass* generates a gradient ranging from 0 at the starting point to 1 at the endpoint, so that everything that is at the start distance or closer to the camera is black and everything that's at the end distance or further away is white.

[image: mist pass output]

Of course you can change the output with a *Color Ramp* for example for finetuning the gradient, or change the *Start* and *Depth* etc., but basically for your question you can now use the *Mist* output as factor to mix the original image with a color to let the objects disappear in the mist of the chosen color:

[image: mix color by mist factor]

Comment: i followed all the steps but its only visible in my final render i cant adjust in it the viewport 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZbQE9SnLSk_ICUgF0MTMBOjf9mE8S3vu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mangojuice This is done in compositing, the effect is not visible in the viewport. You can only see the line that represents start and end in the viewport - as my screenshots show.

Comment: i see i was thinking something more like a ground fog since its calculating the distance from camera some of my scene disappears thanks for the reply though i didnt know about it maybe i will use it someday :3

Comment: @mangojuice Yeah, sorry I realized later that you were looking for ground fog but maybe this helps someone who stumbles over this question while looking for something like this.